# Installling supported version of SAGA to work with QGIS on Windows

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, saga, windows

I'm running into issues with SAGA processing algorithms in QGIS 3.18. QGIS tells me that SAGA 7.8.2 isn't supported, but doesn't tell me which versions are.

I've seen a suggestion that 2.3.x is officially supported, but how do I make QGIS aware of the version I've installed? I've tried downloading and installing SAGA 2.3.1, but QGIS still tells me I'm using the unsupported 7.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling all versions of SAGA and then QGIS, followed by reinstalling QGIS 3.18 did the trick - it installed SAGA 2.3.2 linked to QGIS.